# Cómo mandar datos de un formulario (tablas dinámicas) por post y recibir en un php para insertar en la bd mysql

Tags: javascript

Buenas tardes tengo un ejemplo que he tomado de la pagina (aclaro soy estudiante es para un proyecto) lo que tengo que hacer básicamente es buscar un producto dentro de una ventana modal devolverlo en una tabla dinámica y luego enviarlo por un formulario o otra forma para procesarlo en otra pagina php e insertar en la base de datos: 
Avances:
-Búsqueda en ventana modal (Conseguido pongo como ejemplo datos estáticos) 
-Mostrarlo en tablas dinámica(conseguido)
-Lo que me falta es enviarlo a por post o otro método para procesarlo en un php expongo mi .
Agradecería si alguien me pudiera orientar

```js
function RefrescaProducto() {
            var ip = [];
            var i = 0;
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //Deshabilito el Boton Guardar
            $('.iProduct').each(function(index, element) {
                i++;
                ip.push({
                    id_pro: $(this).val()
                });
                
            });
           
            if (i > 0) {
                $('#guardar').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            var ipt = JSON.stringify(ip); //Convierto la Lista de Productos a un JSON para procesarlo en tu controlador
            $('#ListaPro').val(encodeURIComponent(ipt));

           
        }

        function agregarProducto() {

            var sel = $('#pro_id').find(':selected').val(); //Capturo el Value del Producto
            var text = $('#pro_id').find(':selected').text(); //Capturo el Nombre del Producto- Texto dentro del Select

            /* lazar aca consola*/
            
             console.log(sel)
             
            var sptext = text.split();

            var newtr = '<tr class="item"  data-id="'+sel+'">';
            newtr = newtr + '<td class="iProduct" >'+sel+'</td>';
            newtr = newtr + '<td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="cantidad[]" name="lista_cantidad[]" onChange="Calcular(this);" value="1" /></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="precunit[]" name="lista_precio[]" onChange="Calcular(this);" value="0"/></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="totalitem[]" name="total_item[]" readonly /></td>';
            newtr = newtr + '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove-item"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td></tr>';

            $('#Detalles').append(newtr); //Agrego el Producto al tbody de la Tabla con el id=ProSelected

            RefrescaProducto(); //Refresco Productos

            $('.remove-item').off().click(function(e) {
                $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); //En accion elimino el Producto de la Tabla
                if ($('#ProSelected tr.item').length == 0)
                    $('#ProSelected .no-item').slideDown(300);
                RefrescaProducto();
            });
            $('.iProduct').off().change(function(e) {
                RefrescaProducto();
            });
        }

        function Calcular(ele) {
            var cantidad = 0, precunit = 0, totalitem = 0;
            var tr = ele.parentNode.parentNode;
            var nodes = tr.childNodes;
            for (var x = 0; x<nodes.length;x++) {
              
                if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == 'cantidad[]') {
                    cantidad = parseFloat(nodes[x].firstChild.value,10);
                }
                if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == 'precunit[]') {
                    precunit = parseFloat(nodes[x].firstChild.value,10);
                }
                if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == 'totalitem[]') {
                    totalitem = parseFloat((precunit*cantidad),10);
                    nodes[x].firstChild.value = totalitem;
                }
            }
            // Resultado final de cada fila ERROR, al editar o eliminar una fila
            var total = document.getElementById("total");
            if (total.innerHTML == 'NaN') {
                total.innerHTML = 0;
                // 
            }
            total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML)+totalitem;    
        }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <div class="container">
       <form id="formulario-presupuesto" class="form-material"> 
            <h2>Comprar productos</h2>
            <div id="resp" class="label label-success"></div>
            <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Agregar</button>
            <input type="hidden" id="ListaPro" name="ListaPro" value="" required />
            <table id="TablaPro" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Producto</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Acción</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="Detalles">
                    <!--Ingreso un id al tbody-->
                    <tr>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Total</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><span id="total">0</span> <input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="total_final" name="total_final"  value="0" readonly /></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
            <!--Agregue un boton en caso de desear enviar los productos para ser procesados-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" id="guardar" name="guardar" class="btn btn-lg btn-default pull-right">Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </form>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">

            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar producto a la lista</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Producto</label>
                            <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="pro_id" name="pro_id" data-width='100%'>
                                        <option value="ma001">Mause</option>
                                        <option value="mo002">Monitor</option>
                                        <option value="teg003">Teclado</option>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <!--Uso la funcion onclick para llamar a la funcion en javascript-->
                        <button type="button" onclick="agregarProducto()" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Agregar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

```js
function RefrescaProducto() {
            var ip = [];
            var i = 0;
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //Deshabilito el Boton Guardar
            $('.iProduct').each(function(index, element) {
                i++;
                ip.push({
                    id_pro: $(this).val()
                });
                
            });
           
            if (i > 0) {
                $('#guardar').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            var ipt = JSON.stringify(ip); //Convierto la Lista de Productos a un JSON para procesarlo en tu controlador
            $('#ListaPro').val(encodeURIComponent(ipt));

           
        }

        function agregarProducto() {

            var sel = $('#pro_id').find(':selected').val(); //Capturo el Value del Producto
            var text = $('#pro_id').find(':selected').text(); //Capturo el Nombre del Producto- Texto dentro del Select

            /* lazar aca consola*/
            
             console.log(sel)
             
            var sptext = text.split();

            var newtr = '<tr class="item"  data-id="'+sel+'">';
            newtr = newtr + '<td class="iProduct" >'+sel+'</td>';
            newtr = newtr + '<td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="cantidad[]" name="lista_cantidad[]" onChange="Calcular(this);" value="1" /></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="precunit[]" name="lista_precio[]" onChange="Calcular(this);" value="0"/></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="totalitem[]" name="total_item[]" readonly /></td>';
            newtr = newtr + '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove-item"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td></tr>';

            $('#Detalles').append(newtr); //Agrego el Producto al tbody de la Tabla con el id=ProSelected

            RefrescaProducto(); //Refresco Productos

            $('.remove-item').off().click(function(e) {
                $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); //En accion elimino el Producto de la Tabla
                if ($('#ProSelected tr.item').length == 0)
                    $('#ProSelected .no-item').slideDown(300);
                RefrescaProducto();
            });
            $('.iProduct').off().change(function(e) {
                RefrescaProducto();
            });
        }

        function Calcular(ele) {
            var cantidad = 0, precunit = 0, totalitem = 0;
            var tr = ele.parentNode.parentNode;
            var nodes = tr.childNodes;
            for (var x = 0; x<nodes.length;x++) {
              
                if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == 'cantidad[]') {
                    cantidad = parseFloat(nodes[x].firstChild.value,10);
                }
                if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == 'precunit[]') {
                    precunit = parseFloat(nodes[x].firstChild.value,10);
                }
                if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == 'totalitem[]') {
                    totalitem = parseFloat((precunit*cantidad),10);
                    nodes[x].firstChild.value = totalitem;
                }
            }
            // Resultado final de cada fila ERROR, al editar o eliminar una fila
            var total = document.getElementById("total");
            if (total.innerHTML == 'NaN') {
                total.innerHTML = 0;
                // 
            }
            total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML)+totalitem;    
        }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <div class="container">
       <form id="formulario-presupuesto" class="form-material"> 
            <h2>Comprar productos</h2>
            <div id="resp" class="label label-success"></div>
            <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Agregar</button>
            <input type="hidden" id="ListaPro" name="ListaPro" value="" required />
            <table id="TablaPro" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Producto</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Acción</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="Detalles">
                    <!--Ingreso un id al tbody-->
                    <tr>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Total</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><span id="total">0</span> <input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="total_final" name="total_final"  value="0" readonly /></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
            <!--Agregue un boton en caso de desear enviar los productos para ser procesados-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" id="guardar" name="guardar" class="btn btn-lg btn-default pull-right">Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </form>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">

            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar producto a la lista</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Producto</label>
                            <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="pro_id" name="pro_id" data-width='100%'>
                                        <option value="ma001">Mause</option>
                                        <option value="mo002">Monitor</option>
                                        <option value="teg003">Teclado</option>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <!--Uso la funcion onclick para llamar a la funcion en javascript-->
                        <button type="button" onclick="agregarProducto()" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Agregar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: envia el array pero llega vacio no se cual seria mi error

Comment: asi lo recibo     $data = array();
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {  //Recibo el los valores por POST
        $data[$key] = $value;
       
    }

    
    $acturl = urldecode($data['ListaPro']); //decodifico el JSON
    $productos = json_decode($acturl,true);
    
     print_r ($productos);

Comment: Ufffff para esto seria perfecto angular junto con ajax, pero como no es el caso, deberias probar a ir directamente a la ruta donde tienes tu archivo php, (bueno antes de esto deberias poner datos estaticos para probar), por ejemplo rellenar la variable POST manualmente con los datos que vas a usar en el archivo php alojados en POST guardar el archivo y luego ir a la ruta del archivo mediante la dirección de localhost.

Comment: donde la dirección seria algo como: localhost/nombre_proyecto/archivo.php, ahi dentro debe haber algun problema, si puedes edita la pregunta y muestralo.